# Angular JS website (use of pre-render.io)

Tags: javascript

Hi ProWebmasters Community,

Considering a move to build a highly Angular JS website with around 3 million pages. One of the questions that is constantly coming up is to use https://prerender.io in order to allow the site to be friendly and indexed by search engines.

Is Prerender the only option? Using prerender.io option this allows the one to create HTML snapshots of all pages to allow search engines to crawl the relevant pages. The pressing question is if this is the only option moving forward? Is there another option?

Thanks in advance,
PX

Comment: I recommend to try [ostr.io](https://ostr.io/info/prerendering) they are have lowest rate and support for ES6 (ECMAScript2015)

Answer (score 1):

prerender.io isn't the single alternative. Another one thing you could do, is prerender your pages with PhantomJS and cache them, with things like [this](https://github.com/steeve/angular-seo) or [this](http://www.doz.com/search-engine/angularjs-index-seo).

Comment: Hi Evgeniy, Thanks for the feedback on this topic. Another question that's come up is how does Google/Search Engines get hold of the HTML that's in prerender snapshots and where do I need to keep or store the CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Ghostwriter - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ghostwriter-service

Ghostwriter prerenders your JavaScript website for search engines, SEO tools, social media crawler and your browser.